# IE and Edge returns same response on AJAX request using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

jQuery version: *2.1.4*

Server-side technology: *ASP.NET MVC 5*

Erratic behaviour in browsers: *Internet Explorer 11* and below. Also in latest *Microsoft Edge*

I'm doing an AJAX request like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
        url: "/actions/addPost",
        type: "POST",
        data: { name: "Jesús", ... },
        sync: true,
        success: function(data){
            $("#blog-posts").load("/actions/getPosts");
        },
        error: function(data){
            // show error ..
        }
});
});
```

The `load("actions/getPosts")` will always return the same response, when It should return all the posts. Funny thing is, when I reload the page, it will load all the posts, also, if I request `/actions/getPosts` directly it will return every post correctly. But it's as if the requests had been cached somehow by IE and Edge. In every other browser, Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari, it works nicely.

What's the cause of this issue? How to fix it?

Comment: use `cache:false;`

Comment: Send a `Cache-Control` header along with the `/actions/getPosts` response that disallows caching. That's smarter than using a cache-breaker (which is what `cache: false` would do).

Comment: Awesome! It worked. Please, post a formal answer and I will check it as correct.